# BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() works on one phone and not on the other, both are android 11 (api 30)

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am working on a bluetooth application. When I run the app on my phone and press the button that is supposed to run the startDiscovery() method, it works fine for me. But when I try the same thing on another phone, it doesn't work. It does not start searching for devices. Both phones run Android 11.
This is the code I have:

```
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enableBt();
                txtStatus.setText("Searching...");
                btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
                btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pbLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deviceList.clear();
                addresses.clear();
                setAdapter();
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
```

I have all the necessary permissions written in the AndroidManifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I request from user for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in MainActivity.java. Which should also automatically allow ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.(right?). Both phones get location permission request, and both phones get bluetooth enable request, but only one scans for other bluetooth devices when the btnSearch is pressed.

I tried to ask for BLUETOOTH_SCAN which isn't required for android 11 if I'm right. And I am pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: Just a quick shot - are you granting runtime permissions (or did this manually on the "running" phone) ?

Comment: yes, I am granting runtime permissions. Location permission in this case.